# How to set HikariCP pool size with Play

Tags: playframework, slick, hikaricp

What is the correct way to configure the pool size of HikariCP for Play w/ and w/o Slick?

I've tried this with slick:

```
slick.dbs.default.db.minimumIdle=30
slick.dbs.default.db.maximumPoolSize=30
```

(other properties like connectionTestQuery seem to work this way)

And w/o Slick I've tried various combinations of:

```
play.db.default.minimumIdle=30
play.db.default.maximumPoolSize=30
```

And:

```
play.db.default.prototype.hikaricp.minimumIdle=30
play.db.default.prototype.hikaricp.maximumPoolSize=30
```

I've seen the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/SettingsJDBC), but nothing seems to stick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the correct syntax is

```
play.db.default.hikaricp.minimumIdle=30
play.db.default.hikaricp.maximumPoolSize=30
```

but this [does not seem to work with Slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlickAdvancedTopics#Connection-Pool)

> Furthermore, be aware that any configuration under play.db is not considered by Play Slick.

You can try something like

```
slick.dbs.default.db.numThreads=30
slick.dbs.default.db.queueSize=30
```

Comment: Yea, that works for slick. I'm still trying to figure out the non-slick version.

Comment: for some reason setting this value to 15 opens up 17 connections to the database.  I don't know what the extra 2 are for but thought this would be good to know for someone coming across this thread.  I set this to 19 and all 20 connections where open on my database.

Answer (score 3):

Don't take it a wrong way, actually in slick 3.x, the pool size is decided by numThreads value in configuration, the min size is numThreads, and the max size is numThreads * 5, the configuration value of pool size simple not use at its HikariCP wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

SBT Dependancy HikariCP Connection Pool

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP
libraryDependencies += "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.2"
```

Use HikariDatasource with imports , and use setMaximumPoolSize() method of hikari config, like below

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig

var datasource: HikariDataSource = null


 var hc: HikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hc.setMinimumIdle(--- anything ,depends)
    hc.setMaximumPoolSize(300 or anything)
```

-- set other properties like jdbc url ,user name , password ,database name etc which are needed

set hikari config object to hikari data sourse

```
 var ds: HikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hc);
    datasource = ds
```

and use datasource .